# UIRefreshControl addTarget action causing "unrecognized selector" error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uirefreshcontrol

I have a `UITableViewController` in which I am implementing a `UIRefreshControl` for pull to refresh. Everything is working fine, the table is getting populated from my web service. But when I pull down to refresh I get the error:

```
[MyViewController refreshView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance ...
```

Which is complaining about the addTarget action here:

```
UIRefreshControl * refresh = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
[refresh addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

The error flag on that line in the editor is `Undeclared selector 'refreshView'`

My refreshView method is simply:

```
- (void) refreshView: (UIRefreshControl *)refresh { 
    NSLog(@"test");
}
```

Any ideas as to why this would be causing the application to crash? (I am running iOS 7.1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you declared your method as "`refreshView:`" (i.e. with a parameter), you need to add a colon to the "`@selector`" bit.

In other words, one line changes with one character:

```
[refresh addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Comment: Haha thanks, that fixed it. Will accept once I can. Appreciated